# Alexa spoken text not accepting '<' character

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, multimodal

For alexa spoken text feature, I'm sending a plain text like
"This is a < less than symbol"
but alexa is throwing error. I know '<' character is part of ssml tags like <,>, etc

If I use '>' in the spoken text like "This is a > greater than symbol" it works fine.

This issue is happening only with '<' character.
Any solution?

Comment: Use the XML entity &lt; instead of <,  you should escape all XML reserved characters.